# How to set DataSourceUpdateMode in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I need the DataGridView to update the cell contents OnPropertyChanged, rather to OnValidate.

The DataGridView is bound to a BindingSource, sourced by a subclass of BindingList with custom business objects.

The DataGridView is for selecting the desired object, that is then bound to common controls on the form, so the user can edit it. It is only odd, that the DataGridView does not get updated while the TextBoxes are edited. The business objects support INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject, IDataErrorInfo.

Any ideas on how to achive this?

Comment: who you bind your data to gridview? Manually, or directly giving db table?

Comment: added some information, databinding is done via bindingsource

Answer (score 2):

It seems it does not work directly by changing the `DataSourceUpdateMode`.
You can use the `DataGridView CellContentClick` event to find out when the user clicked on the check box or when the user changed the check by hitting the space bar.

At that point you can execute `DataGridView::EndEdit` to commit the cell column. And then call `BindingSource::EndEdit` to commit the entire row.

You can use the following links to understand and get your solution robust:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/3aa81b24-2911-44ad-baf4-2619557b374e

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/116030/datagridview-lacks-support-for-binding-datasourceupdatemode

Comment: Sadly, the user should not edit the values inside the datagrid directly.